# This block of code gives me a Sequence contains no elements when live, but not locally. Does not have to do with the database connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public ViewResult Index(string inputDate)
    {
        //Enables dates on the DatePicker that have available BlogPosts
        List<string> dates = new List<string>();
        foreach(BlogPost post in repository.BlogPosts)
        {
            dates.Add(post.DatePosted.ToString("M-d-yyyy"));
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        ViewBag.EnabledDays = js.Serialize(dates.ToArray<string>());

        //If no date specified, return the latest one
        if (inputDate == null)
             return View(repository.BlogPosts.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).First());
        //Otherwise return date picked
        else
             return View(repository.BlogPosts.ToList().Where(p => p.DatePosted.ToString("d") == inputDate).First());
    }
```

I truly am confused, I've troubleshooted and honed in on the issue. It's not my database connection, as the code works when entering the page (inputDate is null, so it grabs the most recent BlogPost). That works fine.

Locally when I run my code, both conditions work. If inputDate is not null, it grabs the date you select perfectly. Everything displays fine.

As soon as I publish to the web, the ==null portion works fine, but the "else" errors out, giving me a...

Sequence contains no elements

I'm so in the dark as to what this could be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sequence contains no elements` means it - you are applying `First()` to a sequence, which does not contain elements.

If it is real business scenario for your application, then you should use `FirstOrDefault()` - that will return First entry, if it has any, or `default()`  (which is `null` for classes) otherwise. Then you will need to treat result (null or real value) according to your business rules.

If it is not a real case (that is, `p => p.DatePosted.ToString("d") == inputDate` should always return at least one item), then you have data error - deal with it.

Comment: First off, thank you for the reply.

I completely understand the error message, and why it occurs. My issue is that when the web application is live, this error occurs, when it is local, it doesn't. 

When I'm running locally, it's perfectly fine. That to me points to a database issue, but it also connects properly, so that isn't it either. Local and live both point to the same database on my web server, with the same entries. It's even harder to debug because it only occurs when live.

Comment: So collection is empty while it shouldn't - so that's what you need to isolate. First, I would take a look at `p.DatePosted.ToString("d")` condition - it uses Current Culture, which might be different for your local and server machines, thus providing different `where` condition.

Comment: Thank you sir, that's the kind of local/server difference I'm looking for. I will give that a look!

Comment: CurrentCulture was the solution. Had to explicitly include it in the DateTime ToStrings. In my case I added ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-CA")). Local & Server are working properly now. Thanks!